# Transactional emails: Use case specific sender names?

Tags: email, communication, transactions

I design transactional email communication for a company. My goal is that *sender name*, *sender email*, *email subject* and *email pre-header* (the preview) will help the reader to grasp the email's gist quickly.

In this context I ask myself **if we should use use-case-specific sender names or generic ones?**

```
Use-case-specific senders for fictitious eCommerce company ACME Inc.

° ACME Order confirmation <shipping@acme.net>
° ACME Shipping confirmation <shipping@acme.net>
° ACME Payment confirmation <payment@acme.net>
° ACME Returns <returns@acme.net>
```

```
Example leveraging the pattern above:

Sender:     ACME Shipping confirmation <order@acme.net>
Subject:    Expected delivery in 2-3 days
Pre-header: Order #12345 has been shipped. <link>Track your parcel</link>
```

I notice that many companies use the same sender name for different types of transactional emails (e.g., ACME Inc <hello@acme.net>). In my view the use-case-specific is better, but I wonder if I'm missing clear disadvantages?

Comment: Is there a reason why not?

Comment: Would "ACME Order confirmation <orders@acme.net>" be more use-case-specific?

Comment: @bloodyKnuckles Yes, I think it would be more use-case-specifc. I added an example to clarify.

Comment: "...missing clear disadvantages?" — Compared to what? Compared to something like "Sender: Joe Bloe <joe.bloe@acme.net>" ?

Comment: I don't know the answer overall, but I'd bet that A/B testing using open rates as the metric would help you decide if it's the right move for your company.

Answer (score 1):

Naturally the use-case-specific components: Name, Subject, Preview, speed recognition of intent. The email address, not likely.

*However*, a huge UX advantage of "use-case-specific" email addressing such as `orders@acme.net`—compared to `hello@acme.net` or `info@acme.net`—is efficiently routing email responses, resulting in better customer service.

A consequence, not necessarily a disadvantage, of "use-case-specific" email addressing is any particular customer will have a variety of *Acme, Inc.* email addresses in their email contacts. Do customers need to memorize your company email address? If so, then use-case would make that more difficult.

Comment: Thank you, +1 for pointing out multiple contacts in customers' address books